# Adding characters automatically in react-hooks textInput

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, textinput

I am using react-native with react-hooks. I want to add some characters automatically like '-' or '(space)' in card number and '/' in due date. It should work like below.

If user enter numbers in card number input than '-' should add automatically.
`1234` -> `1234-` -> `1234-5678` -> `1234-5678-`. 
Also at due date, I want to add '/'.
`02` -> `02/` -> `02/23`

```js
const CardAdd = () => {
  const [cardNumber, setCardNumber] = useState("");
  const [dueDate, setDueDate] = useState("");

  onInputChange = (setState, value) => {
    setState(value);
  };

  if (dueDate.length === 2) {
    setDueDate(dueDate + "/");
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Input
        name="Card Number"
        keyboardType="number-pad"
        style={styles.inputContainer}
        placeholder="1234 5678 1234 5678"
        value={cardNumber}
        onChangeText={value => onInputChange(setCardNumber, value)}
      />
      <Input
        name="Due Date"
        keyboardType="number-pad"
        style={styles.inputContainer}
        placeholder="MM/YY"
        value={dueDate}
        onChangeText={value => onInputChange(setDueDate, value)}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

If I do it like this, it does work. It adds '/' automatically when I type in 2 digits at due date. But I can't delete the after than. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: formatted-input module is [here](https://github.com/buttercup/react-formatted-input#react-formatted-input). you can use this to implement the cardNumber input and dueDate input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **useEffect** hook to keep track of the changes of the state and update your state accordingly, I have made some logic about credit card but it may not work, but you can improve the logic

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const CardAdd = () => {
  const [cardNumber, setCardNumber] = useState("");
  const [dueDate, setDueDate] = useState("");

  onInputChange = (setState, value) => {
     if(!isNaN(value)) {
       setState(value);
     }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (dueDate.length === 2) {
      setDueDate(dueDate + "/");
    }
    if(cardNumber.length === 4) {
      setCardNumber(cardNumber+'-')
    }
    if(cardNumber.contains('-') 
   && (cardNumber.length - cardNumber.split("-").length - 1) % 2 === 0 
   && (cardNumber.length - cardNumber.split("-").length - 1) !== 16
) {
       setCardNumber(cardNumber+'-')
    }

  }, [cardNumber, dueDate]) 



  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Input
        name="Card Number"
        keyboardType="number-pad"
        style={styles.inputContainer}
        placeholder="1234 5678 1234 5678"
        value={cardNumber}
        onChangeText={value => onInputChange(setCardNumber, value)}
      />
      <Input
        name="Due Date"
        keyboardType="number-pad"
        style={styles.inputContainer}
        placeholder="MM/YY"
        value={dueDate}
        onChangeText={value => onInputChange(setDueDate, value)}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```